# Remove older cordova version - 4.3 installed but project created in 4.0

Tags: macos, cordova, installation, command

I have installed cordova version 4.0 able to generate 3.6.3 source.
Now installed cordova version 4.3.0 without uninstalling 4.0.0 and while check for Cordova -version returns 4.0.0

First time uninstall using `sudo npm uninstall cordova -g` 
removing 4.3.0 version.

Then check for cordova version returns 4.0.0
For the second time using uninstall command returns below error

```
uninstall not installed in /Users/labuser/node_modules: "cordova"
```

how can i remove 4.0 then update to 4.3 version of cordova?